# Setting WKS to a Variable Sheet CodeName

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 sheet codenames:

```
Summary
Credit
Debit
Comments
```

I want to execute a loop setting the WKS = codename but it's not working because I think when I set the array elements I'm using quotes which makes it more like a string than a sheet?

Code:

```
Dim sheetArray(4) as Variant
Dim wks as Worksheet
sheetArray(1) = "Summary"
sheetArray(2) = "Credit"
sheetArray(3) = "Debit"
sheetArray(4) = "Comments"


for i = 1 to 4
    set wks = sheetArray(i)
    ...do stuff...
next
```

This isn't working for me... instead I have to do this which feels ugly.

Code:

```
for i = 1 to 4
  if i = 1 then
      set wks = Summary
  elseif i = 2 then
  ....etc
```

Any tips on the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the array as worksheets then set each variable. And no quotes

```
Dim sheetArray(4) as Worksheet
Dim wks as Worksheet
Set sheetArray(1) = Summary
Set sheetArray(2) = Credit
Set sheetArray(3) = Debit
Set sheetArray(4) = Comments


for i = 1 to 4
    set wks = sheetArray(i)
    ...do stuff...
next
```

Comment: ah, I didn't notice that he wasn't using the `sheetarray(i)` as a property of `worksheets` - good catch

Comment: @Snoobie, Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me as a variant

```
Sub test()
Dim sheetArray() As Variant
ReDim sheetArray(1 To 3)
sheetArray(1) = "Sheet1"
sheetArray(2) = "Sheet2"
sheetArray(3) = "Sheet3"
Dim ws As Worksheet
For i = LBound(sheetArray) To UBound(sheetArray)
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetArray(i))
   MsgBox (ws.Name)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can set the worksheet name by referencing it directly. Using your first example:

```
Dim sheetArray(4) as Variant
Dim wks as Worksheet
sheetArray(1) = "Summary"
sheetArray(2) = "Credit"
sheetArray(3) = "Debit"
sheetArray(4) = "Comments"


for i = 1 to 4
    wks.Name = sheetArray(i) ###This is the line I changed. Notice wks.Name
    ...do stuff...
next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop through all the worksheets in a Workbook you can do it without using arrays and using their names as variables as it maybe changed at a later stage:

```
     Sub WorksheetLoop()

     ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
     Dim Current As Worksheet

     ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
     For Each Current In Worksheets

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
        MsgBox Current.Name
     Next

  End Sub
```